# Most Optimal TPL Dataflow Design?

Tags: c#, architecture, asynchronous, concurrency, tpl-dataflow

I like to ask for input how to best design the most optimal architecture using TPL Dataflow. I do not have written code yet so there is no sample code I can post. I am not looking for code (unless volunteered) either but assistance in the design would be much appreciated:

The requirements are as follows:

I have 3 core datablocks that are dependent on each other in specific ways. Datablock1 is a producer that produces objects of type Foo1. Datablock2 is supposed to subscribe to Foo1 objects (from Datablock1) and potentially (not upon each and every Foo1, subject to a specific function) produce Foo2 objects that it stores in an output queue for other datablocks to consume. Datablock3 also consumes Foo1 objects (from Datablock1) and potentially produces Foo3 objects that Datablock2 consumes and transforms into Foo2 objects.

In summary, here are the datablocks and what they each produce and consume:

- Datablock1: Produces(Foo1), Consumes(Nothing)
- Datablock2: Produces(Foo2), Consumes(Foo1, Foo3)
- Datablock3: Produces(Foo3), Consumes(Foo1)

An additional requirement is that that the same Foo1 are processed at about the same time in Datablock2 and Datablock3. It would be ok if Foo1 objects are first consumed by Datablock2 and then once Datablock2 has done its work the very same Foo1 objects are posted to Datablock3 for it to do its work. Foo2 objects from Datablock2 can result from either operations on Foo1 objects or Foo3 objects.

I hope this makes sense, I am happy to explain more if it is still unclear.

My first idea was to create TPL Dataflowblocks for each of the 3 datablocks and to make them handle incoming streams of different object types. Another idea is to split up datablocks and have each datablock only handle streams of one single object type. What do you recommend or is there an even better solution that may work?

Svick has already helped on the Datablock1 and it is already operational, I am just stuck on how to go about transforming my current environment (as described above) to TPL Dataflow.

Any ideas or pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking for most efficient architecture, there is only one to properly find that: measure different options to find out which one is actually the best. Everything else will be only guesses.

Comment: Fully agree, but at this point I am not sure whether a datablock can even be setup to accept objects from different ISourceBlocks linked to it. If I knew how to write a datablock that can take, for instance Foo1 and Foo2 objects, buffer them in 2 separate input queues and have the passed in function operate on either then I would be able to setup some testing architecture myself. The problem is that TPL Dataflow documentation is currently pretty much non-existent. Would you be able to help with how to deal with accepting multiple producers passing differnet objects to one dataflowblock?

Comment: Do `Foo1` and `Foo3` share a common base class? If not, how come block 2 can process both?

Comment: They are not sharing any base class. The point is to figure out whether a block can be designed that takes/processes two different streams (of different type objects). Thats the whole point of this exercise to figure out what is doable what not because the TPL Dataflow documentation does not have much to say at least I did not find much. I stumbled across BatchedJoinBlock but am not sure whether it is applicable here...

Comment: @svick, my question was whether a dataflow block can be designed to accept streams of different types from 2 separate datablocks. I think it sounds like a reasonable requirement that TPL Dataflow should provide one way or the other but its just that the documentation is so sparse that I have so far not seen anything that mentions any type of block that can handle multiple data types in their own respective input queues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's split this problem in three and solve each independently.

The first one is how to produce an item conditionally. I think the best option is to use [`TransformManyBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194784%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and let your function return a collection with one or zero items.

Another option would be to [link the two blocks conditionally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462705%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so that `null`s are ignored and return `null` when you don't want to produce anything.
But if you do that, you also have to link the source to a [`NullTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462765%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so that the `null`s don't stay in its output buffer.

The second problem is how to send Foo1s to both block #2 and block #3. I can see two ways here:

1. Use `BroadcastBlock` linked to both target blocks (#2 and #3). Be careful with this, because `BroadcastBlock` doesn't have an output queue, so if a target block postpones an item, it means it won't process it. Because of this, you shouldn't set `BoundedCapacity` of blocks #2 and #3 in this case. If you don't do that, they will never postpone and all messages will be processed by both blocks.
2. After processing Foo1 by block #2, manually `Post()` (or better, `SendAsync()`) it to block #3.

I'm not sure what exactly does “at about the same time” mean, but in general, TPL Dataflow doesn't make any guarantees about the order of processing of independent blocks. You can alter priority of different blocks by using [a custom `TaskScheduler`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx), but I'm not sure that would be useful here.

The last and most complicated problem is how to process items of different types in a single block. There are several ways how to do this, though I'm not sure which will be best for you:

1. Don't process them in single block. Have one `TransformBlock<Foo1, Foo2>` and one `TransformBlock<Foo3, Foo2>`. You can then link them both to a single `BufferBlock<Foo2>`.
2. As you suggested, use `BatchedJoinBlock<Foo1, Foo3>`, with `batchSize` of 1. This means the resulting `Tuple<IList<Foo1>, IList<Foo3>>` will always contain either one `Foo1` or one `Foo3`.
3. Enhance the previous solution by linking the `BatchedJoinBlock` to a `TransformBlock` that produces a more suitable type. That could be either `Tuple<Foo1, Foo3>` (one of the items will be always `null`), or something like the F# [`Choice<Foo1, Foo3>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353439.aspx), which ensures that only one of the two is set.
4. Create a new block type from scratch, that does exactly what you want. It should be `ISourceBlock<Foo2>` and also have two properties: `Target1` of type `ITarget<Foo1>` and `Target2` of type `ITarget<Foo3>`, like the built-in join blocks.

With options #1 and #3, you could also encapsulate the blocks into a single custom block, that looks like the block from #4 from the outside, so that it's more easily reusable.

Comment: Could I clarify what you mean with "producing conditionally"? Is this necessary because TransformBlocks generally place the exact same amount of items in the output queue than arrive in the input queue? Would using an Actionblock and Posting on the condition met be a dirty solution?

Comment: With "at about the same time" I wanted to point out the fact that Foo3s that are produced by DataBlock3 and which are consumed by DataBlock2 depend on the states of certain variables that are set in Datablock2 by Foo1s. I think the only way around this issue is to merge Datablocks 2 and 3. Or to use a different DataBlock for each stream type.

Comment: Yeah, producing conditionally means that only some inputs produce an output. And `TransformBlock` produces the same amount of items as it consumes, yes. In general, I think linking is preferable to posting, but in this case, I guess it's a valid option.

Comment: And having one block depend on some external data goes against the idea of TPL dataflow (and the actor model it's built on). If some block needs something specific for an item, it should come with that item. Because of that, manual `Post()` is probably the best option here, it will make sure the order of operations is correct.

Comment: I chose to option#1, it results in cleaner code and proved fast enough. One question though: Is there a way in an Actionblock to await processing of the next item in the in-queue until the current item has been fully processed not just inside the actionblock itself but if the item was passed on through Post(item) to another data block. Is there some sort of mechanism to report back that the current item is fully processed and to instruct Actionblock to process the next item in the queue?

Comment: The whole idea of TPL Dataflow is that processing in each block is independent. If you want to wait until some processing of an item is finished, then I think that part shouldn't be its own block. You could make it into a normal method that you call from the `ActionBlock`.

Comment: thank you for sharing your vast experience in TPL Dataflow. Sorry, I am not a trained programmer and thus do not know, do you happen to be on the development team of MS TPL Dataflow?

Comment: I'm flattered you would think so, but I have no relation with Microsoft or the Dataflow team.

Comment: I marked your answer as desired solution because it got me going and I decided in the end to implement individual data blocks that each process one characteristic var type. I think its the best trade-off, between raw speed, cleanliness of code, and elegance. I do sometimes have to use Post/SendAsync rather than linking up datablocks but I think I won't currently not get around it easily when outputting items at different frequencies at which items come in. Thanks again for your time and efforts to help with this.

Comment: I just figured out a way to produce 0 or 1 items from `TransformBlock`: write a `transform` lambda that returns `Task.FromResult(value)` to return 1 item and return `null` `Task` to return 0 items. Using `TransformManyBlock` is probably clearer, but this may be also an interesting option.